# UICollectionView get range between two NSIndexPath objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I am working on a calendar using `UICollectionView` and would like to be able to select a range of cells/dates.

**Is it possible to get all of the `NSIndexPath` objects between two indexPath's, so that I can highlight the range?**

Comment: Do you mean is there a method out of the box, or roll your own?

Comment: @danh - Either way. Just looking for a solid solution to this issue.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API: numberOfSections and numberOfItemsInSection to get the all index path range, so you just enum the two index path value, use the above data.

Comment: But, if I wanted to select from the middle of one section to the middle of another, would I just subtract the starting position from that number of rows in that section. And the end position, subtract that from that number of rows in section. Correct?

Comment: yes, you should enum each section of the middle between your start and end.So the every row in the sections will be gotted.